# NHibernate hbm mapping collection whith where condition on boolean property

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, boolean, compatibility

I have an entity A with a bool property (lets call it BProp).
In a second entity there is a bag mapping of A elements with a where condition on BProp like this:

```
<bag name="MyBag" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false" where="BProp = 1">
    <key column="Structure_Id" />
    <one-to-many entity-name="A" />
</bag>
```

The problem is tha BProp = 1 works with SqlServer and Oracle but breaks PostgreSQL which needs a condition like

```
where="BProp = true"
```

Is there a clever way to create a single hbm.xml mapping for all the three db I have to suppport?

Answer (score 1):

As the query substition does not seem to be a usable solution in this filter case, you may go for query interceptor (here a quite rough implementation) :

```
public class BooleanInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor, IInterceptor
{
    public string TrueToken { get; set; }
    public string FalseToken { get; set; }   

    NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        return sql.Replace("{TrueToken}", TrueToken).Replace("{FalseToken}", FalseToken);
    }
}
```

Your mapping would then be `where="BProp = {TrueToken}"`

It would be used like this

```
var interceptor = new BooleanInterceptor ();
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor))
{
    interceptor.FalseToken = "0";  // this replacement value should be taken from a config file
    interceptor.TrueToken = "1";  // see above

    // your code here

    session.Close();
}
```

I bet there are way better solutions, but I hope this will help anyway

-------------------------- previous answer

I use to insert query substitutions in my NHibernate configuration, like this

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect");
.
cfg.Properties.Add("query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
.
```

I guess you could have your xml mapping with `where="BProp = true"` and just insert the cfg property for query.substitions depending if the dialect is MsSql / Oracle or PosgresSQL

Comment: From the documentation and some tries I found out that this property works from HSQL to SQL while the where clause in the hbm file maps directly to SQL so there is no substitution for the "BProp = false".

Comment: @TerenzioBerni thought on another approach. Hope this will be useful. Thx for the follow-up !

Comment: Thank you, currently I'm evaluating the definition of a SafeBoolean UserType which maps a boolean to an numeric column to have the guarantee that on all databases the boolean will be saved as a number.